# Testing memory limit of Python in Windows

Tags: python, memory-consumption

I was trying to probe the Python 32bit memory limit. So I wrote the little program

```
a=[]
while 1:
    a.append(chr(65))
```

and watched the Windows task manager for the memory consumption of python.exe.
Firstly, I was surprised that it is occationally reduced (almost halved sometimes). Second, the amount only goes up to about 500MB (I believe on another 64bit machine it rose endlessly).

The computer has 4GB memory, windows boot>3GB is supposingly active and I patched the python.exe with `imagecfg.exe -l`. No other relevant processes are running and total memory does not exceed 40%. I believe the very same procedure worked on another computer though.

Any suggestions how I can check if my python can go up to 3GB now?

Comment: The memory probably grows slowly because python caches some strings, so every `a.append` actually consumes only 1 word of new memory. Also the allocations are not done for each `append`, but if the list is full then its size is increased by x times.
Anyway, this still does not explain why you wont run out of memory.
For how much time do you let your program run? Have you tried checking the increase in length for `a`?

Comment: Actually I do run of of memory, but with the above version at 500MB (and fairly fast). Now I tried a new programm where I allocate empty classes in a dict. That new one runs about at 1600MB (even faster). I expected to run out at 2000MB or if my patch worked at 3000MB :(

Comment: Try to assign unique strings, python probably referenced to the same object all the time. sys.getrefcount will probably help :)

Comment: But are you sure that you run out of memory, or the program is simply crashing at 500MB? Maybe the reference count is going to 0 or  to a negative value and this causes the program to crash.

Comment: All I'm sure about is that I get a MemoryError exception :) As I use `chr(65)` I expect new objects the be created every time and the memory does indeed go up.